# How to implement the block user feature using Node Express and Sequelize Postgress

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have Postgres DB with the `user` table. with user data 'A', 'B' and 'C'

```
-------------------------------------------------+
| user_id   |   name   |   email   |   is_active |
------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
|      1    |    A     |   a@a.in  |         1   |
------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
|      2    |    B     |   b@a.in  |         1   |
------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
|      3    |    C     |   c@a.in  |         1   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I have implemented the list all user api using sequelize method but now need to implement the block user feature, eg: if the user 'A' blocks user 'B', user 'A' will not get the data of user 'B' and also user 'B' will not retrieve the data of user 'A' but user 'C' need to get the data of user 'B' and vice versa. Here I need to implement the block user feature same like Instagram or Facebook using node express and sequelize postgres.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is a many-to-many relationship between users-to-users. This resolves by creating an intersection table defining which users have blocked which other users.

```
create table user_blocks_user( user_id    integer references users(user_id) 
                             , blocked_id integer references users(user_id)
                             , constraint user_blocks_user_pk
                                          primary key (user_id, blocked_id)
                             ) ;
```

To list the users which a targeted user has not blocked you join `users` to `users` and eliminate the entries that exist in the intersection table.  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zWub4G-K))

```
select bu.*
  from users ub    -- user blocking
  join users bu    -- blocked user
    on true
 where ub.user_id = <user_id>      -- targeted user
   and ub.user_id <> bu.user_id    -- eliminate self  
   and not exists (select null     -- eliminate users blocked by targeted user  
                     from user_blocks_user ubu
                    where ubu.user_id = ub.user_id 
                      and ubu.blocked_id = bu.user_id
                  );
```

Sorry, but I do not know your obscurification languages ( Node Express, Sequelize) so I leave the translation to you, or just use native SQL.